# Как вставить перенос строки в phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Когда в программе phpMyAdmin редактирую данные в поле (комментарии пользователей), то при нажатии enter поле просто закрывается, а хотелось бы перенести строку, раньше эту проблему обходил вставкой br, но сейчас этот вариант не подходит.

Comment: shift+enter / ctrl+enter ?

Comment: о! супер, спасибо.